# WCF / Entity framework update

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity-framework, caching

I am currently building a N-Tier application where I have a WCF service (not data / RIA services) hosted on a web project on my IIS server, and a Windows Phone client with a Service Reference pointing on this WCF service.

My WCF service access to the database through Entity Framework.

Here is my problem : 
When I update my database from anywhere but the client, the update cannot be seen in any clients.
When I update my database from a specific client, the modifications can only be seen by him.

But after a while, all clients have access to the updated data.

I believe it can be caused by a IIS caching of my WCF's datas, or a caching at LINQ level, but the problem remains even after disabling my IIS caching.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: How do you handle EF context's lifetime in the WCF service?

Comment: the context is created in another class with expose a dictionnary of context regarding of the client (WP7, android, web). I tried to use the "refresh" method of the context on my object to reload the data on call, but it didn't change anything

Comment: Mire than likely the framework is caching, not iis. Try re-establishing the context between calls and make sure you're not extended the unit of work or turning the context in to a singleton pattern.

Comment: indeed, the problem came from that. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turn this in to a formal anwer:

The Framework will attempt to cache values (not IIS). So, ensure you are not extending the Unit of Work beyond the scope of the transaction (i.e. using it for both the same and the retrieve method(s)). Also, try re-establishing the context between store/retrieve calls which should remove any existing caching that may be occurring within the framework. i.e.

```
[OperationContract]
public void Save(MyObject entity)
{
  using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
  {
    db.MyObjects.Add(entity);
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
}

[OperationContract]
public MyObject Single(Int32 id)
{
  using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
  {
    return db.MyObjects.Single(x => x.Id == id);
  }
}
```

As opposed to:

```
[ServiceContract]
class MyService
{
  private MyEntities db = new MyEntities();

  [OperationContract]
  public void Save(MyObject entity)
  {
    this.db.MyObjects.Add(entity);
    this.db.SaveChanges();
  }

  [OperationContract]
  public MyObjectFind(Int32 id)
  {
    return this.db.MyObjects.Single(x => x.Id == id);
  }
}
```